# Custom ValidationAttribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validationattribute

I tried to create a custom ValidationAttribute:

```
public class RollType : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return false;   // just for trying...
    }
}
```

Then I created (in another class) -

```
  [RollType]
  [Range(0,4)]
  public int? Try { get; set; }
```

on the view (I use MVC) I wrote:

```
      <div class="editor-label">
            Try:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Try)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Try)
        </div>
```

The validation for "range" works great, but not for the custom one!

What can be the problem?

Comment: Note that `RollTypeAttribute` is the recommended name for this class. You can still use `[RollType]` with that new name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
public class RollType : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      return new ValidationResult("Something went wrong");
   }
}
```

Also do not forget to check if modelstate is valid in code behind or else it won't work, Example

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SomeObject object)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Insert code here
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Error 1 'RollType.IsValid(object, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)' 
"

Comment: Sorry I just fixed the mistake, it need to be protected override not public override, it will work now.

Comment: Also if you want to ass a success message use  'return ValidationResult.Success;'

Comment: Thanks! I deleted everything I did and start from begining and used your code and now it works.. :)